# setHours() javascript returns a diffrent format then expected

Tags: javascript, milliseconds, gettime

I have this situation where I am in need of using the JavaScript

> setTime()

So that I can modify the time, according to a number of seconds I have.  For example I want to know what time it was 1400 sec ago.

I come to the conclusion that my cleanest and best solution it would be to use a combination of

*getDate()* and *setHours()* - *setMinutes()* - *setSeconds()*  like in the example in this link: 
https://codepen.io/Jaquelline/pen/rPgOKj?editors=1011

```
function myFunction() {
var myTime = new Array();
    for(i=0; i <3599; i++){
     var d = new Date();
     var currentI = 3599-i;
        myTime[i] = new Array();
        myTime[i] = {
          x: i,
          y: d.setHours(d.getHours()-1) + ':' + d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()) + ':'+ d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds()+currentI)
        };
    }

var s = JSON.stringify(myTime);
document.getElementById("cTimeArray").innerHTML =s;


 var t = new Date();
 t.setHours(t.getHours()-1);
 t.setHours(t.getMinutes());
 t.setHours(t.getSeconds()+1200);
 document.getElementById("cTime").innerHTML =t;
}
```

The ***s***  variable returns something like this:

> [{"x":0,"y":"1550821508351:1550821508351:1550825107351"}, 
>    {"x":1,"y":"1550821508351:1550821508351:1550825106351"},

While  ***t*** returns :

> Sun Apr 14 2019 08:45:08 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

Comment: By calling `t.setHours` multiple times, you are overwriting what you set before each time. And stuff like `t.setHours(t.getMinutes())` makes little sense to begin with.

Comment: So, what is the question? Why `setHours` returns a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the correct value.

Set `d` before and use the getters to show the value.

```js
var myTime = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < 3599; i++) {
  var d = new Date();
  var currentI = 3599 - i;
  myTime[i] = {};

  d.setHours(d.getHours() - 1);
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes());
  d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + currentI);
  myTime[i] = {
    x: i,
    y: d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds()
  };
}

var s = JSON.stringify(myTime);
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to know the time 1400 seconds ago, then why not just subtract 1400 seconds from the current time?

```
var past = new Date((new Date().getTime()) - 1400 * 1000);
```

`getTime()` returns the timestamp representing the date/time in milliseconds, hence the multiplication of 1400 by 1000.

Comment: Simple and clean. Perfect.

Comment: In this case I would be needing to show just the HH:MM:SS